# JdbcTemplate Reading a table with a list of filter values (with AND and LIKE )and returning a list of string

Tags: java, sql, jdbctemplate

How should I go about creating a Java method that can perform this operation?

```
        SELECT * FROM test.new_table
        WHERE IDS LIKE "%101G%"
        AND IDS LIKE "%14F%"
        AND IDS LIKE "%701G%"
```

I realized that my current code is OR operation rather than AND

```java
public List<String> readFileNamesBy(String tableName, String categoryName, List<String> filterValues) {
        String sql = "select * from " + tableName + " where "+ categoryName + " like ?";
        JdbcTemplate jt = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);


        final List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String filterValue : filterValues){
            jt.query(sql,
                    new Object[] { filterValue },
                    new RowCallbackHandler() {
                        public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
                            fileNames.add(rs.getString("FILE_NAME"));
                        }});
        }
        return fileNames;
    }
```

Note that `List <String> filterValues` could vary in length... so that's why I decided to go with a for loop here.

Btw Idk if it matters but I'm using Java 8 (since that's what this whole program is written) and I can't really do anything about it..

And here is my implementation of the method (fyi)

```java
        List <String> filterValues = Arrays.asList("%101G%", "%14F%");
        List <String> hi = dbUtil.readFileNamesBy("test.new_table","IDS", filterValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to build a filter method to take the values input and then construct them as SQL select statement in a dynamic way
suppose that the values that comes from user input is a Map object like this:

```
    Map<String, String> searchTerms = new HashMap<>();
    searchTerms.put("IDS", "101G");
    searchTerms.put("IDS", "14F");
    searchTerms.put("IDS", "701G");
```

Then you can generate the SQL query using buildSelectQuery method bellow:

```
public String buildSelectQuery(Map<String, String> searchTerms, String tableName) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("SELECT * FROM ").append(tableName).append(" WHERE ");

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : searchTerms.entrySet()) {
        String column = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue();
        sb.append(column).append(" LIKE '%").append(value).append("%' AND ");
    }

    sb.delete(sb.length() - 5, sb.length()); // Remove the trailing " AND "

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Finally, you can generate the SQL select query by calling the mentioned method:

```
    MyQueryBuilder qb = new MyQueryBuilder();
    String query = qb.buildSelectQuery(searchTerms, "test.new_table");

    System.out.println(query);
```